# Connect app policy : All users may self authorize

Tags: connected-apps

what is oauth policy 'all users may self authorize'?
[image]

How this change may impact the jwt server to server integration?

Thanks in advance for the clarification! :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage_oauth.htm&type=5) documentation,

The OAuth policy **'All users may self-authorize'** is an option that allows all users in a Salesforce org to authorize a connected app after successfully signing in. A connected app is an application that can access Salesforce data through the OAuth 2.0 protocol. Users must approve the app the first time they access it, and then they can use the app without further authorization.

***All users may self-authorize** — Default. Allows all users in the org to authorize the app after successfully signing in. Users must approve the app the first time they access it.*

***Admin approved users are pre-authorized** — Allows only users with the associated profile or permission set to access the app without first authorizing it. After selecting this option, manage profiles for the app by editing each profile’s Connected App Access list. Or manage permission sets for the app by editing each permission set’s Assigned Connected App list.*

**PS::**

As per the comment, I have added a simplification of the statement "Allows all users in the org to authorize the app after successfully signing in. Users must approve the app the first time they access it."

The statement means that:

- All users in the org can use the connected app after they log in to Salesforce with their username and password. They do not need to enter any additional credentials to use the app.
- Users must approve the app the first time they access it. They will see a screen that shows the app name, logo, and the permissions that the app is requesting. They can choose to allow or deny the app access to their Salesforce data.
- After the users approve the app, they can use it without further approval. The app will receive an access token that can be used to access the protected resources on Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks for sharing insights from salesforce documentation, I am not getting good understanding over this statement 'Allows all users in the org to authorize the app after successfully signing in. Users must approve the app the first time they access it.??? what does it mean? please simplify it for better understanding.

Comment: @DSK, I have added a simplified answer please check.

Comment: Jad, Thanks! how it will be working in jwt server-to server integration? in that flow, user will not be involving in the flow since it is token based.